# Strategy for unique user-voting such as Stackoverflow's?

Tags: php, zend-framework, spam-prevention, voting

I noticed that for voting SO implements an XHR method which POSTs to a posts controller and sends the post ID and vote type through the URL, in addition a `fkey` parameter is sent, eg:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1/vote/2
```

I'm going to be implementing a similar technique, I'm wondering what logic I could use to prevent duplicate voting by the same user and prevent spamming, in addition to overall logic when implementing this.

The schema for the table I'll be storing them:

```
thread_id   user_id   vote_type
2334        1         2
```

So far I came up with these bullet points:

- ensure the user is logged in
- ensure that a valid post ID and valid vote type is sent
- ensure that after POSTing, the user has not previously voted
- the code that creates the hash can't contain dynamic information such as user agent, since a user could be on a different browser, different OS, right?

**Update:**

"SO is probably using the login cookie to identify the user." - Andrew

Could someone demonstrate how this would be done, or in other words more specifically provide an example of how the `fkey`, which is an alphanumeric 32-bit string, is generated?

**Question:**

- since I'm not sending the actual user id anywhere with my XHR code, does this mean I have to update my table schema so that I can store the `fkey` instead of say, the `user_id`? The `fkey` will probably have to be unique to each user, and so I can probably query whether there is a row in the voting table that has an fkey of whatever.

Would appreciate any tips or insight on anyone who's implemented a similar technique.

Comment: Why are you not sending the actual user id anywhere with your XHR code?

Comment: well, I noticed that SO wasn't using it, and possibly for a good reason.. one could create a custom form, put a user id field with a value, and POST it and it would be a valid request, no? However, if you use something like the `fkey` chances are no one will be able to reverse-program it to get the same hash based on the user, which is why I think SO uses this method.

Comment: SO is probably using the login cookie to identify the user. I checked with Firebug, and cookies are being sent.

Comment: Isn't this logic partly implemented in your database.  1 post many different votes?  If the userid is in the vote table for that post then don't allow additional upvotes.  If downvoted, remove entry from vote table.

Comment: For morons like me: XHR = XHMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Andrew - can you demonstrate an example of how they'd be doing that?

Answer (score 2):

create UNIQUE index on fields (thread_id, user_id) and DBengine will protect you from multy comments on one thread :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just sign the URIs somehow in order to prevent users from manipulating valuse. For instance, you could hash parts of the URI with a secret and append the hash to the URI. When users copy the URI and change values, the URI and the signed part become invalid.

This is often done in RESTful APIs, and your current approach is similar to.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how badly you want to keep people from re-submitting or fiddling with your data. Nothing will be 100% (unless your budget is through the roof), but you can do a good job of keeping most people from resubmitting by:

- check their UID - or generated ID from the UID (I will explain)
- record their IP address, and check against the DB for the IP and the submission ID (along with the generated UID)

Using the IP solution alone, can be defeated by using a proxy of course, or a connection that changes IP's often such as the DSL carrier in my city (but even then, its every couple of days). I personally generate a unique key based on that persons UID, and pass that back and fourth if necessary. A salted MD5 hash usually works fine, or even an AES implementation if MD5 is viewed as too weak. Combined together, you should have a good starting place.

Comment: can you include examples of md5 plus a salt in this context, along with the user id?

Comment: $new_uid = MD5($user_name."this is my salt");
with $new_uid, you can store this value into the database that will be unique to each member. Of course I am assuming that each member already has a unique ID such as an email address that this is based off of (for $user_name).
You can then perform a query against their ip - $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
and the unique ID generated with the salted MD5 hash. Its not perfect, but a base to work off of.